# Can I disable to Chromebook developer mode warning?

Tags: google-chrome-os

Every time I turn on my Chromebook (I actively use developer mode for running Linux) I get a warning that disk verification is disabled.

How can I remove this warning without losing access to developer mode?

Answer (score 0):

The approach as [described here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/replace-chromebook-bios/) which works by flashing SeaBIOS.

Note that this method is only available for (certain) Intelish (as x86-64 architecture) processors.

I'm still waiting for a viable solution for the ARM-based computers as my Acer R13 Chromebook.